# In D3 Sankey, how can I load the from objects or arrays instead of either json or csv files?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

Level: Beginner.

I'm looking at sankey implemented in D3 and the examples shown seem all to use data from JSON or CSV instead of simply using objects or arrays. The one or two that may do it differently seem to use a long walk around instead of simplifying the matter.

Is there a way to just load the data in code instead of having to format data as an external file? Thanks!

An example of available code: http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/c2637e28b79fb3bfea13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your data available without doing any async operations then you can achieve this as follows, replace the `d3.json` line

```
d3.json("sankey-formatted.json", function(error, graph) {
  // ...
})
```

With your custom loading function e.g.

```
loadData(function (graph) {
  // contents of the function passed to d3.json
})
```

The function `loadData` now receives a function as a parameter which should be called with the data you have, which can be a plain JS object

```
function loadData(cb) {
  var data = {
   "nodes":[
    {"node":0,"name":"node0"},
    {"node":1,"name":"node1"},
    {"node":2,"name":"node2"},
    {"node":3,"name":"node3"},
    {"node":4,"name":"node4"}
    ],
    "links":[
    {"source":0,"target":2,"value":2},
    {"source":1,"target":2,"value":2},
    {"source":1,"target":3,"value":2},
    {"source":0,"target":4,"value":2},
    {"source":2,"target":3,"value":2},
    {"source":2,"target":4,"value":2},
    {"source":3,"target":4,"value":4}
    ]}

    // invoke the function passed as an argument
    cb(data)
}
```

This would be the hard way, the easy way would be to get rid of that function and have a `graph` variable holding the data directly

```
var graph = { /* the nodes and links are here */ }
// contents of the function passed to d3.json
```